# How do I set maintenance window on Heroku Redis?

Tags: heroku, redis

Whenever I try to set the maintenance window for Redis on my app, I get the following:

```
❯ heroku redis:maintenance:window:update "Sunday 3:00" -r production
 ›   Warning: redis:maintenance:window:update is not a heroku command.
Did you mean pg:maintenance:window? [y/n]: n
```

I have set the maintenance window for PG, the part I am worried about is Redis.

The docs / cli help has redis and data:mainteance listed as commands

`heroku redis:maintenance`

but

`heroku data:maintenances:window:update`

is not.

Has anyone else had this issue? Is their CLI tool borked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to [install the maintenance CLI plugin to use those commands](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis-maintenance):

> You can also manage your planned maintenance with the [Data Maintenance CLI Plugin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/data-maintenance-cli-commands) commands. [Install the plugin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/data-maintenance-cli-commands#installation) before running the `data:maintenances:*` commands in this article.

You can install the plugin by running

```
heroku plugins:install @heroku-cli/plugin-data-maintenance
```